# Create additional database in server using sql injection

Tags: sql-injection

I'm trying to do an sql injection in DVWA with Apache2 and MySQL that would create one more database.
This: `2' union select 1,2' create database kala;#--` does not give me any errors but it also does not create the database.

DVWA security setting is set to low.

Answer (score 1):

First, determine if you can use a 'create' statement in a query like that.